# Getting definition of -f Linux flag tougher than expected

Tags: shell, terminal, rm

Terminal beginner here. I was reading through [a tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and encountered the following command:

```
rm -f src/*
```

For my own edification, I want to know what `-f` does.

However, when I enter in `man -f`, I get the error response `What manual page do you want?` and when I run `man f`, I get the response `No manual entry for f`.

What's the correct way to get the definition of `-f` in this context from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`-f` is parameter of the `rm` program. It doesn't have same meaning for all programs so you have to look manual page of the program. `man rm` in your case and it says:

```
f, --force
ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

For instance in `tail`, `-f` parameters means follow (output appended data as the file grows) You can learn that from `tail`'s manual page which is `man tail`

Comment: Just curious, you usually feel like you can scroll down the documentation to see what the flag means, or is the documentation sometimes so long that you use `vim` or `grep` commands to find what you need?

Answer (score 1):

`-f` in this context is a flag you add to `rm`. You'll see it documented under `man rm`. The relevant part of the output will show that

> -f, --force
>       ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt

Comment: Just curious, you usually feel like you can scroll down the documentation to see what the flag means, or is the documentation sometimes so long that you use vim or grep commands to find what you need?

Comment: @zthomas.nc Most pagers (the default is usually [`less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less)) allow you to search in them, so you won't need to use `grep`